# How to pass a parameter from angular 2 service to node js function? MEAN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a **posts** collection and each post has an **id** and **userId**.

I want to find all **posts** for a specific **user** (using userId property)..

here is my angular2 service:

```
    export class PostsService {

    private _url = '/api/posts';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._url).map(res => res.json());
    }
    getUserPosts(userId: number) {
        return this._http.get(this._url + '/' + userId).map(posts => posts.json());
    }
}
```

and my nodejs code :

```
router.get('/posts', function(req, res) {
    post.find({}).exec(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR FETCHING POSTS!!");
        } else {
            res.json(posts);
        }
    });
});


router.get('/posts/:id', function(req, res) {
    post.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR FETCHING POSTS!!" + err);
        } else {
            res.json(posts);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Still you got stuck on this ??

Comment: Yes...any idea ):?

Comment: can you add your mongoose post Schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send `query params` to the backend to be able to filter them in you nodejs controllers.In your Angular Service you'll have something like this:

```
export class PostsService {

    private _url = '/api/posts';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._url).map(res => res.json());
    }
 getUsersPost():Observable<Post[]>{
    let params - new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('user_id', userIdValue );
    return this._http.get(this._url, { params: params }). subscribe(....more code)
}
    getUserPosts(userId: number) {
        return this._http.get(this._url + '/' + userId).map(posts => posts.json());
    }
}
```

the final URL would be something like this: `/api/posts?user_id=userIdValue`.You need to import `HttpParams` from `'@angular/common/http'` I'm supposing you have Angular > 4.3, for  more info about `HttpParams` refer to [Angular Official Doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters)

Now, you just have to filter your post in your nodejs controller:

```
router.get('/posts', function(req, res) {
let query = {};
if(typeof req.query.user_id != 'undefined'){
    query['createdBy'] = req.query.user_id // supposing that 'createdBy' is where you store the user id's in post scheme 
}
    post.find(query).exec(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR FETCHING POSTS!!");
        } else {
            res.json(posts);
        }
    });
});
```

If the `user_id` query param is not provided the `post.find` function will return all posts, if it is provided will return all the posts created by that user.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanx bro...can you give me any link  for a live example?

Answer (score 0):

Complete this tutorial before jump into code.

```
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/
```